# How to reduce temperature difference between the second floor and basement?

Tags: basement, thermostat, temperature

I have one thermostat on the second floor and while it is achievable to get a desired temperature on the second floor, the basement is always cold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a central heating system? Adjust the dampers in the basement to full open and close them down on the upper floor, if you have AC you will need to reverse them in the summer or close the lower floors dampers and open the upper floor dampers. I like control dampers on the main ducts to each floor so there are only 2 adjustments, 1 in summer and 1 in winter instead of having to adjust all of them.

Comment: Yes, central heating/cooling system one for the whole house. Is there a way to install the control dampers on existing system?

Comment: You're telling the home owner to close off the warm air supply to the space that has the thermostat. Not very good practice. And if he starts messing around with to many dampers he just might decrease the airflow across the heat exchanger. Not a good thing to be doing.